# Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, branch.io

I have integrated branch.io for deep linking in my app and enabled associated domain capability, added associated domains as well. But I am getting this error given below while trying to upload this new build to app-store from application loader.

*`ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'myapp-prod.app.link' for key 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload/DragonSlayer.app/DragonSlayer' is not supported."*`

I saw a lot of similar posts but none of them helped me. Hence posting as a new question. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried removing and adding entitlement again?

Comment: thanks for the response, tried that but it didn't work. Tried clearing derived data, clean and all sorts of things like that but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include 'applinks:' in front of the link domain.  This should resolve this error.

Comment: Thanks man that was the issue, i don't know how i missed that. I was stuck for two days